# Filtering a (Nx1) list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of the form

```
[(2,3),(4,3),(3,4),(1,4),(5,4),(6,5)]
```

I want to scan the list and return those elements whose `(i,1)` are repeated. (I apologize I couldn't frame this better)

For example, in the given list the pairs are `(2,3),(4,3)` and I see that 3 is repeated so I wish to return 2 and 4. Similarly, from `(3,4),(1,4),(5,4)` I will return 3, 1, and 5 because 4 is repeated.

I have implemented the bubble search but that is obviously very slow.

```
for i in range(0,p):

    for j in range(i+1,p):
        if (arr[i][1] == arr[j][1]):
            print(arr[i][0],arr[j][0])
```

How do I go about it?

Comment: Your question title says "sorting", but the question body sounds more like "filtering". What's the expected result? Do you want a nested list like `[[(2,3), (4,3)], [(3,4), (1,4), (5,4)]]`? Also, do the repeated numbers have to be adjacent? What if the input is `[(1,2), (3,4), (2, 2)]`?

Comment: Just sort the list using a function which looks at the second element of each tuple, and then traverse it.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I apologise. You are indeed correct, I did want to "filter" the list.

I only want the (0, i) element if i is repeated.

The repeated numbers are always adjacent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`. This will return a mapping from the second item to a list of first items. You can then filter for repetition via a dictionary comprehension.

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [(2,3),(4,3),(3,4),(1,4),(5,4),(6,5)]

d = defaultdict(list)

for i, j in lst:
    d[j].append(i)

print(d)

# defaultdict(list, {3: [2, 4], 4: [3, 1, 5], 5: [6]})

res = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if len(v)>1}

print(res)

# {3: [2, 4], 4: [3, 1, 5]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy allows to avoid for loops:

```
import numpy as np
l = [(2,3),(4,3),(3,4),(1,4),(5,4),(6,5)]

a = np.array(l) 
items, counts = np.unique(a[:,1], return_counts=True)
is_duplicate = np.isin(a[:,1], items[counts > 1]) # get elements that have more than one count
print(a[is_duplicate, 0]) # return elements with duplicates

# tuple(map(tuple, a[is_duplicate, :])) # use this to get tuples in output
```

(toggle comment to get output in form of tuples)

pandas is another option:

```
import pandas as pd
l = [(2,3),(4,3),(3,4),(1,4),(5,4),(6,5)]

df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=list(['first', 'second']))
df.groupby('second').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
```